# K(X) is a finitely generated field extension of $K$, but it is not ring-finite over $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I am currently working through Algebraic Curves by W. Fulton, and I am having a rough time understanding the section "Modules; Finiteness Conditions". I have muscled through Fulton exercise 1.41 and 1.43, but I am still not confident.

> 1.44:Show that $L=K(X)$ is a finitely generated field extension of $K$, but $L$ is not ring-finite over $K$

Hint: If $L$ were ring-finite over $K$, a common denominator of ring generators would be an element $b\in K[X]$ such that for all $z\in L$, $b^nz\in K[X]$ for some $n$; but let $z=1/c$, where c doesn't divide $b$.

Comment: What is causing problems ? I find the hint to be clear.

Comment: Maybe first convince yourself that $\mathbb Q$ is not ring-finite over $\mathbb Z$.  The argument is the same, but the setting may be more familiar.

Comment: @Schipperus I don't know what "a common denominator of ring generators" means.

Comment: Never mind, I managed to figure it out! Thank you.

Comment: @Purple, I have just started Fulton and wonder what does "ring-finite" mean? Can you explain it, please?

Answer (score 4):

If $K(X)$ were ring-finite over $K$, there would be $\frac{f_1}{g_1},\ldots, \frac{f_m}{g_m}\in K(X)$ which generate $K(X)$, in the sense that any $G\in K(X)$ could be written as a polynomial in them. Take $G=1/h$ where $h$ is some "ugly" to-be-determined polynomial. Then we have $$ \frac{1}{h} = \frac{H}{g_1^{e_1}\cdots g_n^{e_n}} $$ for some (natural) exponents $e_i$ and some $H\in K[X]$. To finish one can take an irreducible $h$ that has higher degree than all the $g's$. Alternatively, take an $h$ which has a root (in $\overline{K}$, the algebraic closure) that is not shared by any of the $g_i$'s.